# Android Studio: What is the correct mainfest data for a Google sign-in Intent?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-manifest, google-signin

What I'm practicing on now is signing a user into their Google account so I can then access Achievments and Leaderboards.

Using Google's instructions, I came up with this code...

```
public class GmeAchvs extends Activity {


// Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions.
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

// Client used to sign in with Google APIs
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;




public void preSets(){
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


}


public void signinCheck(){
    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    //updateUI(account);
}


private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        //updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w("signInException", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        //updateUI(null);
    }
}









public void signInSilently() {
    Log.d("silentsignin", "signInSilently()");

    mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("signinsuccess", "signInSilently(): success");
                        //onConnected(task.getResult());
                    } else {
                        Log.d("signinfailed", "signInSilently(): failure", task.getException());
                        //onDisconnected();
                    }
                }
            });
}



public void signOut() {
    Log.d("signingout", "signOut()");

    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("signoutsuccess", "signOut(): success");
                    } else {
                        //handleException(task.getException(), "signOut() failed!");
                    }

                    //onDisconnected();
                }
            });
}




 }// end of class
```

If I researched correctly, you have to declare all Activities in the manifest...which brings me to my question for this post...

What would the Action and Category be for this kind of Activity?

```
    <activity android:name=".GmeAchvs">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I know it's not the Main and I don't think it's supposed to be LAUNCHER either.
Do I even need that little "." before the Activity name?

Comment: What I did was, instead of creating a java class for Google Sign In, I created a new empty activity and moved my code to it.  By doing that, I was able to look at the mainfest and see the new activity defined by name...but that's it.  So it looks like providing an action and category is not needed.....I think.  Now I just have to figure out how to start the new activity from main activity and go back to main activity when the signin is completed.

Comment: I also added to the manifest, the values that label the mainactivity as the parent activity.  
After running the app, I started getting the error code of 10 (user error) after the sign in attempt.  Turns out, Google has a tone of loops you have to jump through in order to just sign into a google account for the purpose of testing achvs and leaderboards.  "Geezus Kryst" Google.  Now I'm missing my Ap_Id, which I can't seem to locate because it's not listed on the play console and it's supposed to be a number.

Comment: I just noticed, the value I got from setting up SHA1 on the Google Cloud, it has a 12 digit number but a lot more follows it.  I'm guessing that's what I'm supposed to use for Ap_Id but do I use the first 12 numbers or the whole thing....???  Google said the id is usually 12 digits....  Google is so confusing.

Comment: Yay!  I created a string xml and went ahead and added the whole string I got from my Google cloud setup to Ap_Id for the manifest and it worked..I was able to do a successful signin.  It's all still confusing though...  Like, I'm doing all this for a debug test app I will not be making public but what if it was a real app?  Wouldn't I have to redo things under my cloud because the signing key won't be a debug key anymore....  "Geezus" Google.... Mercy!